# Proxy array has a key with the same name as a method name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `Proxy` that my constructor returns, and I am not sure how to fix the issue of when I add items to an array of key value objects like so `{key: 'abc', value: 123}` and the key is the same as a method in the object such as `get`, and I try to call the method `example.get()` I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: example.get is not a function

If I don't add an item with the key `get` the method runs and there is no error.

```js
class Example {

  constructor() {
    this.items = []
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, key) {
        let item = target.items.find(i => i.key == key)
        if (item) return item.value
        return Reflect.get(target, key)
      }
    })
  }

  get(key) {
    return this.items.find(i => i.key === key).value
  }

  add(key, value) {
    this.items.push({
      key,
      value
    })
  }

}

let example = new Example

example.add('nonvalue', 'a non value')
example.add('get', 'myvalue')

console.log(example['nonvalue'])
console.log(example.get('nonvalue'))
```

Is there a way to know if something is called via method or by array key?

Comment: I don't think the issue is that you are trying to figure out whether `get` is called as a method or from an Array, it's the fact that it is looking up the property at all and you are intercepting that action and handing back what you supplied with `add()`.  What do you **want** to happen?

Comment: What I want, is if `example['get']` is called it should get from the array, if `example.get()` is called it should run the method.

Comment: A method is a property in JavaScript. It's just a property that returns a function. So behind the scenes, `example.get()` is doing `example['get']`, then trying to call it as a function.

Comment: What about `example['get']()` then?

Comment: that would call the method since it is being called as a method. So, if it is called as a method I would like it to call the method, if it isn't called as a method I would like it to get the array value.